# add seconds to a date

Tags: c, unix, datetime

I need to add seconds to a date.
For example, if I have a date such as 2009127000000, I need to add the seconds to this date.
Another example, add 50 seconds to 20091231235957.

Is this possible in C?

Comment: I think the date format in your example is underspecified. 2009127000000 could be the 7th of December or the 27th of January.

Comment: @benjamin, have a read of the man pages for ctime (date / time conversion functions) and strptime (converts string representation of a time to a time tm structure)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The C date/time type time_t is implemented as the number of seconds since  a certain date, so to add seconds to it you simply use normal arithmetic. If this is not what you are asking about please make your question clearer.

Comment: `time_t` is commonly seconds, but isn't necessarily so.

Comment: Beware that this answer is not correct all the time. Please see the @MichaelBurr's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1860996/1776916

Answer (score 41):

In POSIX a `time_t` value is specified to be seconds, however that's not guaranteed by the C standard, so it might not be true on non-POSIX systems. It commonly is (in fact, I'm not sure how often it isn't a value representing seconds).

Here's an example of adding time values that doesn't assume a `time_t` represents seconds using the standard library facilities, which are really not particularly great for manipulating time:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    time_t now = time( NULL);

    struct tm now_tm = *localtime( &now);


    struct tm then_tm = now_tm;
    then_tm.tm_sec += 50;   // add 50 seconds to the time

    mktime( &then_tm);      // normalize it

    printf( "%s\n", asctime( &now_tm));
    printf( "%s\n", asctime( &then_tm));

    return 0;
}
```

Parsing your time string into an appropriate `struct tm` variable is left as an exercise.  The `strftime()` function can be used to format a new one (and the POSIX `strptime()` function can help with the parsing).

Comment: how do I get back a `time_t` from the modified `then_tm`?

Comment: @Lazer: `mktime` returns the `time_t` you want.

Comment: @Michael Burr. This will be true only if seconds is less then 60. I mean otherwise you have to do the entire calculation yourself

Comment: @abhi why? it works with any seconds you want: 50, 200, 3600, 86400 etc. Obviously the user will know how much time is 3600 seconds.

Comment: No guys, the seconds and minutes you have to manage yourself. Adding 120 to `tm_min` gives something like `Current time: 19:56:21 will fire at: 19:176:21` using `std::put_time(my_tm,"%X")`

Answer (score 12):

Use types and functions from [`<time.h>`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/time.h.html).

```
time_t now = time(0);
time_t now_plus_50_seconds = now + 50;
time_t now_plus_2_hours = now + 7200;
```

[`<time.h>`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/time.h.html) declares functions that deal with `time_t` and `struct tm` types. These functions can do all you want.

Comment: Should be the answer. Clean, clear, and has excellent examples. +1

Comment: Updated `<time.h>` from POSIX 2016: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/time.h.html

Comment: This is the universal answer other does not properly solves

Comment: This does not work if time_t is not expressed in whole seconds (not guaranteed on all platforms).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:  (Note: no error checking)

```
include <time.h>

char* string = ...;
char  buf[80];
struct tm;
strptime(string, "%Y%m...", &tm);
tm->tm_isdst = 0;
strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y%m...", localtime(mktime(&tm) + 50));
```